# Сортировка массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в данном коде сделать перебор массива `sortmass` и сделать визуальное окно куда надо вводить цифры, например, вводим в визуальное окно 3.5 и нажимаем на пункт по убыванию и массив сортирует цифры по убыванию, потом также, например, вводим число 5 и ставим, например, по возрастанию и массив сортирует цифры по возрастанию.

Собственно вот сам код:

```
<form method="post">
    По возрастанию <input type="radio" name="type" value="1" checked="checked" /><br />
    По убыванию <input type="radio" name="type" value="0" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="sort" value="Отсортировать" />
</form>
<br /><br />

<?php 
$arr = array(1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$count = count($arr)-1;
sort($arr);
if(isset($_POST['sort'])) {
    echo $_POST['type'],'<br><br>';
    if(!empty($_POST['type'])) { #сортировка по возрастанию
        for($i=0;$i <= $count; $i++)
            $new_arr[] = $arr[$i];
        echo 'Сортировка по возрастанию:<br />';
    }
    else {
        for($i = $count; $i >= 0; $i--)
            $new_arr[] = $arr[$i];
        echo 'Сортировка по убыванию:<br />';
    }
var_dump($new_arr);

}
?>
```

Comment: никто не знает?

Comment: Может и знает. Только вот я просто не очень понимаю, что именно вы хотите. И [может сортировать как-то по другому](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qr1-ix0)?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы покопал в сторону сортировки массива с помощью кастомных функций. Очевидный плюс — легкость в добавлении новых функций. Выглядит код примерно так:

```
<?php
var $array; # Массив
var $mode; # Название функции для сортировки

function asc($a, $b) {
    # Алгоритм сортировки по возрастанию"
}

function desc($a, $b) {
    # Алгоритм сортировки по убыванию
}

$mode = "desc";

usort($array, mode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $x = [1, 8, 3, 9, 6, -8, 12, -51, 41, 54];
     $y = [];

        function number($x, $y)
        {
            if ($x != []) {

                foreach ($x as $key => $item) {
                    $min = $x[$key];
                    break;
                }

                foreach ($x as $key => $item) {
                    if ($item < $min) {
                        $min = $item;
                    }
                }

                foreach ($x as $key => $item) {
                    if ($item == $min) {
                        $y[] = $item;
                        unset($x[$key]);
                    }
                }

                number($x, $y);

            } else {
                print_r($y);
            }
        }

        number($x, $y);
```

Мой вариант сортировки без стандартных функций (sort, ksort, usort и all).